# Confusion about Chern connection one form formula

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, holomorphic-bundles

Let $(E,h)$ be a holomorphic Hermitian vector bundle with local frame $\{e_i\}$. Denote by $H$ the matrix of $h$ in $\{e_i\}$.  I found two different expression for the Chern connection 1-form $\omega$:

In some place it says that $\omega=H^{-1}\partial H$ and in other it says $\omega=\partial H\cdot H^{-1}$. Are they actually the same? if not is there a mistake? if yes which one is the true one?

First expression: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/ChernConnections.pdf

Second expression: [https://www.math.uh.edu/~shanyuji/Complex/Geom/cx-26.pdf](https://www.math.uh.edu/%7Eshanyuji/Complex/Geom/cx-26.pdf)

Comment: They are *not* the same, and both are correct. As always in differential geometry, it depends on whether the group action (change of frame) is on the left or on the right.

Comment: @TedShifrin How is this related to the change of frame ? When we develop the formula we get the equality of matrices $\partial H = \omega\cdot H$ which should give us $\omega = \partial H \cdot H^{-1}$. Now you are saying that this depends on a convention. Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: It seems like the first one is correct. In the second note, there was a mistake on page 105 where the author claimed $\langle \omega^\gamma_\alpha s_\gamma, s_\beta\rangle = h_{\beta\bar\gamma}\omega^\gamma_\alpha$ but it should have been $\omega^\gamma_\alpha h_{\gamma \bar\beta}$ instead.

Comment: @lEm I just picked two random examples, you can find the second convention in Griffiths-Harris as well, page 73.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken. Ted was right. There are two conventions for changing frames, one is multiply by left (e.g. as in Griffiths, Harris) and another by right (e.g. page 3 of Kobayashi https://old.mathsoc.jp/publication/PublMSJ/PDF/Vol15.pdf). You can see how the difference in convention of change of frames already affected the formula for connection 1-forms in the same page.

Answer (score 1):

This confused me also and still does, but I will try to explain what I have understood so far. For the following discussions, let us denote the matrix of connection 1-form by $\theta$ and the curvature 2-form by $\Theta$.

Apparently there are two ways to define $\theta$ according to either you act $\theta$ on the left or right of the vectors (or coordinate representaion of it). Namely, you define either $\nabla e_j = \theta_{ij}e_i$ or $\nabla e_j = \theta_{ji}e_i$. Note that this two conventions result in difference of taking transpose of $\theta$. As a result, we see two different structure formulas for $\Theta$ :

$\Theta = d\theta+\theta\wedge\theta$ or $\Theta = d\theta-\theta\wedge\theta$.

In the second convention (which is used by for example GH and Fangyang Zheng), we have the formula for $\theta$ in terms of $h_{i\bar{j}}$ :

$\theta=\partial h \cdot h^{-1} $

hence in the first convention this becomes :

$\theta=(\partial h \cdot h^{-1})^t = {h^t}^{-1}\cdot\partial h^t = {\bar h}^{-1}\cdot\partial \bar h$

by the Hermitian symmetry of $h$. (this is what you see in Demailly)

But this still isn't what we see sometimes, i.e. $\theta= h^{-1}\cdot\partial h$. And it seems that there is another conventional difference for the expression of $h$ also.

Usually we write down coordinate expression for $h$ by $h=h_{i\bar j}dz^i\otimes d\bar z^j$. This means that in local coordinates, Hermition inner product takes the following form :

$(a,b)_h=a^t h\bar b=a^i h_{i\bar j}\bar b^j$.

On the other hand, we can enforce our Hermition inner product to have alternative expression like this (which resembles more of a real case) :

$(a,b)_h=b^*ha=\bar b^j h_{\bar{j}i}a^i$

where $*$ means conjugate transpose.

Hence we have an alternative expression for the inner product as well $h=h_{\bar{j}i}dz^i\otimes d\bar z^j$, which result in the transpose of the matrix for $h$. Note that this does nothing in the real case, but in the Hermition case this is equivalent to taking conjugation for the matrix of $h$.

Now if we take this convention for $h$ and the first convention for $\theta$, we get the desired $\theta = h^{-1}\partial h$.

The convention for $h$ that I described is used by for example, "Calabi–Yau Manifolds with Torsion and Geometric Flows" by Sébastien Picard.

Unfortunately this is not the end of the story. If we take $h_{i\bar j}$ convention, the natural expression for $h^{-1}$ would be $h^{\bar{j}i}$, so that $h^{\bar{k}i}h_{i\bar j}=\delta^{k}_{j}$ and so forth. But it seems that some authors use $h_{i\bar j}$ for $h$ and $h^{i\bar j}$ for $h^{-1}$ hence resulting in another differences.

It seems to me that the best way to deal with this kind of ambiguity is that to remember how certain expressions change under different conventions, and combine it to get the correct formula under the given convention from what you have already know.