# Calculating $\partial H_j\cdot H^{-1}_j$ where $H_j$ is the hermitian structure

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $(E,h)$ be a hermitian holomorphic vector bundle and suppose we have local trivializations $U_i$ and $U_j$ with transition maps $g_{ij}$. Let $H_i$ and $H_j$ represent the matrices of $h$ with respect to the trivializations $U_i$ and $U_j$. We have that $H_j=g^T_{ij}H_i\bar{g}_{ij}$. I'm trying to prove the following equation

$$
\partial H_j\cdot H^{-1}_j=g^{-1}_{ij}(\partial H_i\cdot H_i)g_{ij} + g^{-1}_{ij}\partial g_{ij},
$$

but I've ran into some issues.

What I currently have is the following. We write $H_j=g^T_{ij}H_i\bar{g}_{ij}$ and then

$$
\begin{align*}
\partial H_j=\partial(g^T_{ij}H_i\bar{g}_{ij})=(\partial g^T_{ij})H_i\bar{g}_{ij} + g^T_{ij}(\partial H_i)\bar{g}_{ij}+g^T_{ij}H_i(\partial \bar{g}_{ij}).
\end{align*}
$$

Now if I'm not mistaken $\partial \bar{g}_{ij} = 0$ so this reduces to

$$
\begin{align*}
\partial(g^T_{ij}H_i\bar{g}_{ij})=(\partial g^T_{ij})H_i\bar{g}_{ij} + g^T_{ij}(\partial H_i)\bar{g}_{ij}.
\end{align*}
$$

Multiplying this thing from the right by the matrix

$$
H_j = (g^T_{ij}H_i\bar{g}_{ij})^{-1} = \bar{g}^{-1}_{ij}H^{-1}_i(g^T_{ij})^{-1}
$$

we obtain

$$
\partial H_j\cdot H^{-1}_j=(\partial g^T_{ij})(g^T_{ij})^{-1} +g^{T}_{ij}(\partial H_i)H^{-1}_i\bar{g}_{ij}.
$$

This is not quite what I wanted, but I can't figure out where am I making a mistake?

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Left and right actions seem to be muddled up. Write down precisely what the transition functions of the bundle mean and how you arrive that at the equation relating $H_j$ and $H_i$.

Comment: Which part makes no sense? Is it the equation $H_j=g^T_{ij}H_i\bar{g}_{ij}$? @TedShifrin

Comment: The way I do it I get $gHg^*$, but I suspect your transition functions are the transpose of mine. But, no, it's that your connection matrix is $\partial H\cdot H^{-1}$ and the transformation has $g^{-1}$ on the left rather than right.

Comment: So for a section $s_j$ you have something like $h(s_i,s_i) = h(g_{ij}s_j, g_{ij}s_j)=g_{ij}\bar{g}_{ij}h(s_j,s_j)$? I need to check if using this $gHg^*$ resolves my issue. @TedShifrin

Answer (score 1):

If $H_i = g_{ij}H_jg_{ij}^*$, then, writing $g=g_{ij}$ for ease of notation, we calculate as follows. Note that, as you said, $\partial g^* = (\partial\bar g)^\top = 0$, since $\bar\partial g = 0$.
\begin{align*}
\partial H_i\cdot H_i^{-1} &= \partial (gH_jg^*)(gH_jg^*)^{-1} = \partial g(H_jg^*(g^*){}^{-1}H_j^{-1})g^{-1} + g(\partial H_j)(g^*(g^*){}^{-1})H_j^{-1}g^{-1} 
\\
&= dg\cdot g^{-1} + g(\partial H_j\cdot H_j^{-1})g^{-1},
\end{align*}
as desired.

Comment: How did you obtain $H_i = g_{ij}H_jg_{ij}^*$ as I seem to be getting this the other way around as $H_i = g_{ij}^*H_jg_{ij}$? @ted-shifrin

Comment: The indices you've chosen for the trivialization make it a little awkward to write matrix entries, so let's now use $e_\alpha$ as a holomorphic frame for $E|_{U_i}$ and $e'_\alpha$ as a holomorphic frame for $E|_{U_j}$. Then, writing $g=g_{ij}$, we have $e_\alpha = \sum g_{\alpha\beta}e'_\beta$. Then $(H_i)_{\alpha\bar\beta}  = \langle e_\alpha,e_\beta\rangle = \sum g_{\alpha\gamma}\bar g_{\beta,\delta}\langle e'_\gamma,e'_\delta\rangle = \sum g_{\alpha\gamma}\bar g_{\beta,\delta}(H_j)_{\gamma\bar\delta}$, so $H_i = gH_jg^*$.

Comment: This looks like we had the transition functions somehow being switched up. Do you define the trivializations as $\varphi_i : E|_{U_i} \to U_i \times \Bbb C^k$ or as $\varphi_i :  U_i \times \Bbb C^k \to E|_{U_i}$? I would indeed need these to be in different order as $$g^{-1}dg + g^{-1}(\partial H_j\cdot H_j^{-1})g$$ @ted-shifrin

Comment: I use the former, but how are you defining transition functions? There are a lot of conventions to iron out. Every reputable book on complex geometry should have this nailed down, although left/right conventions may differ.

Comment: I use the former as well and I define them via $\varphi_i \circ \varphi^{-1}_j$. This term $\partial H_j\cdot H^{-1}_j$ is actually coming from the Chern connection and I was reading two different books and now I'm convinced that my problem is rooted in how they treat matrices... The other author has $H^{-1}_j \cdot \partial H_j$ instead. @ted-shifrin

Comment: Right. You have to work consistently with one approach. In the differential geometry setting, it's all about whether the frame bundle is a principal bundle with the group action on the left or right. What this translates to is whether we consider matrices multiplying vectors on the left or right.

Comment: I'm quite sure I have the same issue as you discussed here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4215676/confusion-about-chern-connection-one-form-formula). Should the term $H^{-1}_j \cdot \partial H_j$ yield the desired equation that I was first aiming for? @ted-shifrin